# Get content of facebook like box plugin with curl

Tags: php, facebook, curl, yql, facebook-likebox

I'm working on a website which should be fully visible for users in a place that Facebook.com is banned for them. so my Facebook like box plugin will not appear for them. ( in order to not localize this question, assume that I want to bypass all client-side firewalls and show like box plugin as a simple HTML in my website (my website is not banned there)).

My server can access Facebook.com and I thought that i can get content of my plugin using curl (in my server's computer) and then execute and show content of that page as a simple HTML in any part of my website. So I just wrote following script:

```
<?
$c = curl_init('https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fstevejobs&amp;width=292&amp;height=258&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: www.facebook.com', 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
', 'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5', 'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7', 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);



$html = curl_exec($c);

if (curl_error($c))
    die(curl_error($c));

$status = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($c);
?>
```

Surprisingly above code works for https://www.youtube.com( which is banned there too ) or https://www.google.com but not working with that URL or even simply https://www.facebook.com in my server.

Another question : if I use https://www.youtube.com instead of Facebook.com I still can't get CSS files or Javascript files which used in YouTube.com( because they are banned too and clients can't download it either). I just can see texts and some images. I also want curl to automatically get content of CSS and Javascript files.

I also used YQL in order to get content of like box plugin from Facebook.com but I got following result:

YQL statement:

```
select * from html where url = 'https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fstevejobs&amp;width=292&amp;height=258&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false'
```

Result:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng"
    yahoo:count="0" yahoo:created="2011-11-11T11:41:10Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <diagnostics>
        <publiclyCallable>true</publiclyCallable>
        <url
            error="Redirected to a robots.txt restricted URL: https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fstevejobs&amp;amp;width=292&amp;amp;height=258&amp;amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;amp;show_faces=true&amp;amp;border_color&amp;amp;stream=false&amp;amp;header=false"
            execution-start-time="1" execution-stop-time="6"
            execution-time="5" http-status-code="403"
            http-status-message="Forbidden" proxy="DEFAULT"><![CDATA[https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fstevejobs&amp;width=292&amp;height=258&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false]]></url>
        <user-time>6</user-time>
        <service-time>5</service-time>
        <build-version>23377</build-version>
    </diagnostics> 
    <results/>
</query>
```

It looks like there are some problem with facebook.com's robots.txt. I should mention that above YQL statement works for other websites( like https://www.youtube.com or https://www.yahoo.com ).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Setting Host: is CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER isn't necessary; it's set for you automatically. And setting an Accept-Encoding header unilaterally is a bit dodgy, if the client doesn't support both types of compression. It could be that Facebook is using various heuristics in the request to try to keep robots out, and this request isn't sufficiently similar enough to a browser's request to pass their checks. Are you sure you don't need a cookie for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are mistakes in your code:

**1-** change $c to $ch in all parts of your code.

**2-** add "echo $html" after curl_exec function.

**3-** as @Dan mentioned in a comment, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER isn't necessary. simply remove it.

**4-** setting curlopt_cookiejar isn't necessary but I always set it with curl. ( just to make sure that everything works fine )

**5-** remove everything before `<!DOCTYPE` in order to show content properly.

try following code:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fstevejobs&width=292&height=258&colorscheme=dark&show_faces=true&border_color&stream=false&header=false');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT , 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; fr; rv:1.9.1.1) Gecko/20090715 Firefox/3.5.1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR , "facebookcookies"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fstevejobs&width=292&height=258&colorscheme=dark&show_faces=true&border_color&stream=false&header=false"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$html = curl_exec($ch);

//remove everything before <!DOCTYPE
echo preg_replace('/^[^<!]*<!\s*/', '<!', $html);

if (curl_error($ch))
    die(curl_error($ch));

// Get the status code
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($ch);
```